# Token is not cleared when signOutUser(...) is called

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have used this sample to integrate a bot in MS Teams

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth

I needed to configure a third party OAuth provider and had all sorts of trouble doing so. Thanks to a smart gentleman on another thread, I am now able to authenticate my user with such provider.

Here's a quick example of the conversation flow. Don't mind the buttons in French, Oui is Yes and Non is No. On first boot of the application, when I click on the Sign In button, my provider's authentication windows opens and shows the auth form just fine.

[image]

However, when it comes time to logout the user and I type "logout" as indicated within this code sample

[image]

If I type anything else to log back in, I am instantly showed that I'm logged in, the authentication window opens and closes instantly and my token remains obtainable. How do I go about actually clearing that token? I don't feel like this is the intended behaviour, as shown by the docs here:

[image]

Do I have to clear it manually? If so, how should I approach this?

Thanks for any help you can provide on this

Note: I have tried to revert back to the default sample, with an AzureAD v2 connection and the result is the same. I login just fine with my Azure AD account, but the token persists even after a logout.

**EDIT**
Following the sugestions, here are additional screenshots

This is some info from the Context object passed down to the Interrupt

[image]

This is the content of the AuthenticationContext available in the Context object above

[image]

Note that I get my Success when I call the logout endpoint that was suggested

Comment: The sample code is maintaining the state of context,it saves the token for silent login, You can make an call to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout and write the logic for clearing the token from your cache, and set the login_prompt = always

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, that's the whole point. I have no clue how it is saved to "cache". tokenResponse always exists, and is never "saved" explicitly to the bot's MemoryStorage (UserState here, I assume). There's nothing in the docs that even comes close to addressing this. Isn't the point of signOutUser(...) to handle the clearing of that cache? Seems counter intuitive to say the least...

Comment: Yes it's userState which is getting saved in blob, if you see the code the context is getting passed for signoutUser() method, Let me check if have any bug related to this or needs to be created. But the approach i suggested you can use while you signout your can call the logout endpoint, it will end your current session.

Comment: I was able to call the logout endpoint you suggested, but it makes no difference, the token still persists. I have updated the OP with additional screenshots if that can help

Comment: Code is written like this for storing the token, may be in future this will get changed, but as of now we don't have any plan to change this behavior